# shareKit allocation growth

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments, sharekit

Im creating an e-mail via shareKit with an image and canceling it with following actions: "Sharing an Image" -> Share -> Email -> Cance-> Delete the draft (say x6 times).The allocations grow after each loop of this actions and are not released after delete the draft. There are no memory leaks. Is that a reason to worry ? Why is that ?

Thanks in advance for any answers!